# sharepoint 2010 splistitem with ows prefix

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint app, takes values from a form, inserts into lists.

It inserts fine into `li["fieldname"]`, but suddenly in the last day, when I edit and try to update `li["fieldname"]` I get `value does not fall within the expected range`

In the immediate window I type `li` to view its contents and see all fields with a prefix of `ows_` so that my `fieldname` doesn't exist. However if I type `li["gibberish"]` I get an entirely different error than this expected range error.

The field is numeric and in all cases has nothing in it. it blows up when doing `li["fieldname"] != null`

I don't know if the `ows_` issue is causing this or something entirely different. It's almost like the field has some sort of corrupt data in it.

Appreciate any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently deleting the field and recreating it solved this problem.